# Extracting css file name using Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I want to get `style.css` from this string using RegEx

`http://domain.net/jitwp/wp-content/themes/strappress/style.css?ver=3.1.1`

So far, I've tried `\/(?:.(?!\/))` but it gets `/style.css?ver=3.1.1`.  I'm not sure how to ignore the query string at the end or skip the forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[^/]+\.css
```

Or use `\w` which matches word characters:

```
\w+\.css
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wF7vV2/1)

Comment: @jugg1es it does, see above demo.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use the following regex

```
[\w_\-]+\.css
```

Because the following inludes whitespace characters

```
[^/]+\.css
```